# What are "accessors" in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Like the picture, I do not understand the means of the accessors , Does anybody who knows ?

this is the Code below

```
// KVC - overridden to access generic dictionary storage unless subclasses explicitly provide accessors
- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key;



// KVC - overridden to access generic dictionary storage unless subclasses explicitly provide accessors
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key;
```

Answer (score 2):

Accessors are simply methods which provide read and write access to an instance variable.

For more info relating this matter read the following link.
It's old but still usefull for you I guess.

[More info](http://www.cocoalab.com/?q=node/47)

Comment: That link is now dead.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

accessors : accessors are nothing but getters and

mutators : mutators are nothing but setters.

Take a look at this link : http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

also take a look at : [Please explain Getter and Setters in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425827/please-explain-getter-and-setters-in-objective-c)

Comment: @JamesWebster Both getters and setters are called accessors.